# Pyautogui use size() to get two integers

Tags: python, pyautogui

so I am trying to create a bot in python, and for that cause I would need the size of the screen as two integers (x coordinate and y coordinate). I use pyautogui for that case, but the function size() only returns a string:

```
Size(width=2560, height=1440)
```

How would i go about "extracting" these values into integer variables?

edit: I managed to fix my problem, it's some spagetthi code, but I can clean it up later, just in case someone has the same problem:

```
import pyautogui


screen_size = str(pyautogui.size())
screen_size_x, screen_size_y = screen_size.split(",")
screen_size_x= screen_size_x.replace("Size(width=","")
screen_size_y = screen_size_y.replace("height=","")
screen_size_y = screen_size_y.replace(")","")
screen_size_y = screen_size_y.replace(" ","")
screen_size_x = int(screen_size_x)
screen_size_y = int(screen_size_y)
print(screen_size_x)
print(screen_size_y)
```

Comment: Hi! Could you show your code that gets you to this point?

Comment: Ill need to see more code to make a good answer. It would be helpful to read on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello, I managed to fix my problem, with the code I added to my question, thanks though :)

and my minimal, complete, verifiable example would have been this:
import pyautogui
screen_size = pyautogui.size()
print(screen_size)

Comment: Is **pyautogui.size()** really just a string?  If so, why are you converting it to a string yourself by wrapping it in str()?

Comment: Oh yeah, I added that part as a test (idk why, I just tried some stuff) and forgot to remove it. It doesn't make a difference though afaik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found multiple examples online of using pyautogui.size().  In all those examples, that method returns a two-item tuple containing width and height.  So it seems that your code could be as simple as:

```
screen_size_x, screen_size_y = pyautogui.size()
print(screen_size_x)
print(screen_size_y)
```

This is shown in the first example in the pyautogui docs:  https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/README.md

If you did need to parse the string you mention, here's a cleaner way to do that:

```
import re
str = "Size(width=2560, height=1440)"
m = re.search(r"width=(\d+).*height=(\d+)", str)
screen_size_x, screen_size_y = int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2))
print(screen_size_x)
print(screen_size_y)
```

Comment: Yeah, I also only found the examples that give with and height as numbers, but for some reason, it doesn't for me? Anyays, thanks for your help, and that way is indeed cleaner, I am just a newb at programming, so I tried my best to make it short and clean - unsuccessfully haha

Comment: I'd like to help you figure out the original problem, because I'm really curious why it doesn't work like the examples for you.  Maybe an earlier version or something?  I'm curious what the Size object is.  Are you sure size() returns a string?  What does this code produce:  **print(type(pyautogui.size()))** ?

Comment: I'm a regular expression weenie.  I would suggest that as a new programmer, you embrace regular expressions.  They are the same in every language you'll come across, and they can do amazing things.  I've given answers to a few SO questions where someone else gave a page of code for an answer, and my answer was like 5 lines.  I'd be happy to help you with learning regular expressions if you want. - their downside is they aren't very readable to anyone who doesn't know regular expressions.  In this case, however, I bet you think my solution is even a bit more readable.

Comment: the output was exactly this "<class 'pyautogui.Size'>" without the "

And about the regular expressions: I didn't know what they were before your answer, but I have already done some research on it, and it's actually really really useful, so thanks for that :)

Comment: So the output isn't a string, it's a Size object.  So you ought to be able to access its 'width' and 'height' attributes, or otherwise get integer values out of it for those quantities.  Like possibly: **screen_size_x, screen_size_y = pyautogui.size().width, pyautogui.size().height**

Comment: Oh okay, didn't know that, as you can see, I am really new to python, and programming in general. I am really thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from inspect import getsource
print(getsource(pyautogui.size))
```

output:

```
def size():
    """Returns the width and height of the screen as a two-integer tuple.

    Returns:
      (width, height) tuple of the screen size, in pixels.
    """
    return Size(*platformModule._size())
```

nicer code:

```
import pyautogui

x,y = pyautogui.size()
x,y=int(str(x)),int(str(y))
print(x)
print(y)
```